# How to compare software version in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in my database which contains all the softwares, versions installed in clients.

I need to prepare a report to IT department to suggest that how many clients are conformed with the latest version.

Below is my table schema and data:

```
SoftwareText                Versions            
Cognos TM1 Client ENU       10.2.0.1 R4
Cognos TM1 Client ENU       10.2.2 R1
Cognos TM1 Clients ENU      10.2.2 R2
Cognos TM1 Clients ENU      10.2.2 R3 

Cognos TM1 Client DEU       10.2.2 R4
Cognos TM1 Clients DEU      10.2.3 R2
```

The expected output like below:

```
Over all Major Version is 10.2.3 R2
Over all Minor Version is 10.2.0.1 R4

Over all Major version in ENU is 10.2.2 R3
Over all Minor version in ENU is 10.2.0.1 R4

Over all Major version in DEU is 10.2.3 R2
Over all Minor version in DEU is 10.2.2 R4
```

Please suggest to achive.

I tried something as below from but not able to

```
SELECT
  VersionNumber,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VersionNumber) AS ReleaseOrder
FROM ReleaseHistory;
```

Comment: Not able to what? You are on the right track, you should select softwaretext too and then select from this query.

Comment: @sen you should store numeric representation of version number or identity col for it. If this is a one-time job - normalize major/minor/release/build/patch numbers with leading zeros to have similar digit number on each position. split-normalize-concat.

Comment: Thanks for the above. since the software and version integration comes from different internal source, i need to build a logic in my DWH. if you have some logic to implement please let me know